# Removing X-Frame-Options being added automatically only in Login page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, iframe

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application which needs to be loaded inside an `iframe` in another website. But the login page just won't appear inside the `iframe` because an Header is being sent in the response `X-Frame-Options` which is set to `SAMEORIGIN`. Browser is not displaying the page in `iframe` because of this. I already Googled and tried multiple things but nothing worked.

I am using ASP.NET forms authentication. May be in this case IIS adds this header in login page for added security. But I need to get rid of this in my use case.

I tried adding a custom header

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="ALLOW" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

But the `SAMEORGIN` is still being added in the header with comma.

I also tried adding Header value from C# using `Response.Headers["X-Frame-Options"] = "ALLOW"`. It cause two headers with the same name.

I also tried this in web.config

```
<customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Frame-Options" />
</customHeaders>
```

It also didn't worked.

Comment: Try adding this to your Application_Start() method inside Global.asax: `System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;`. MVC 5 adds an X-Frame-Options header automatically

Comment: You seem to be doing everything right, by any chance is it possible that your login page is not part of the application where you are making the config changes.

Comment: @ShashankChaturvedi My Login page is the part the same application.

Comment: @FlorianHaider Your solution worked, Thanks a lot. Please add this as an answer.

Comment: `AllowAll` is the value you want

Answer (score 36, accepted):

MVC 5 automatically adds an X-Frame-Options Header, so go to your `Global.asax` file and add this to the `Application_Start()` method:

```
System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
```

Please note that especially for a login page it is bad practice to remove this header, because it opens up your site for login credentials phishing attacks. So if this site of yours is publicly accessable I strongly recommend to keep this header.

Comment: Thanks for the note but I need to open my login page inside an `iframe`.

Answer (score 27):

Old question, but for other people searching for similar question, you can remove the `X-Frame-Options` in specific actions using the following solution:

First, add this code to method `Application_Start` in `Global.asax.cs` (as @Florian Haider said):

```
System.Web.Helpers.AntiForgeryConfig.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;
```

This will suppress the header in *all actions*. Add a new file named `NoIframeAttribute.cs` containing the following code:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyApplication
{
    public class NoIframeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Set("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
        }
    }
}
```

Add the following line to `RegisterGlobalFilters` method in `FilterConfig.cs`:

```
filters.Add(new NoIframeAttribute());
```

Now, we have the header added to all actions again. But now we can remove it when needed. Just add the following line wherever needed:

```
Response.Headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
```

Comment: `filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Set("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN")` should be `filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN")`

Comment: This answer is the only one I found (on SO or otherwise) that works for disabling X-Frame-Options for a single page.