# My own content does not load in iframe because of cross-origin framing

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am developing a simply feature that allows my partners (other websites) embed our content on their websites within an iframe.

I am testing and strangly some pages are allowed, some are not.

For example:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="500" width="900" src="https://www.mywebsite.com"></iframe>
```

throws console error:

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.mywebsite.com/ does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

while this:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" height="500" width="900" src="https://www.mywebsite.com/experience/"></iframe>
```

renders without problem.

What can be the problem?

Can I explicitly allow rendering my content in iframe from outside source? How to do it?

**EDIT**

My web.config now looks like this:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
  <add name="Cache-Control" value="public" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

But it still doens't work, eg. it doesn't allow to see the iframe content.

I checked the network response and noticed in both `iframe` requests the header is properly set:

```
access-control-allow-origin *
```

however in the first first iframe request I get additionally this:

```
x-frame-options SAMEORIGIN
```

while in the second (experiences) `x-frame-options` is not set at all.

After adding this to the `web.config`:

```
<add name="X-Frame-Options" value="ALLOW-FROM *" />
```

both iframes return console error about cross-origin disallowed and in the second case

```
x-frame-options SAMEORIGIN
```

is not removed, just:

```
x-frame-options ALLOW-FROM *
```

been added in addition.

**EDIT 2**

I have tried to remove the x-frame-options in web.config and also made sure it is not set on IIS for the site but still it persists when I fetch the url:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
    <remove name="X-Frame-Options" />
    <add name="Cache-Control" value="public" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <!--<add name="X-Frame-Options" value="ALLOWALL" />-->
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

[image]

I have been trying to add `x-frame-options ALLOWALL` as you can see above (I commented it then) but it did not remove `x-frame-options SAMEORIGIN`

Answer (score -1):

You can configure your server to provide the right http headers to allow for CORS. This will solve your problem. See here for more info: https://enable-cors.org/server.html

The way CORS works, is to verify that the two domains or sub domains that you are trying to work across (ie your site + https://www.mywebsite.com) are meant to be allowed to be used together. If this wasn't the case, you could suffer from an attack where your internet banking was hosted in an iframe but wrapped by parent content etc, that would facilitate low trust with users.

Typically when you configure CORS you see the headers noted in this article here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin which adds:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

The star allows all other sites to wrap that content in an iframe etc, but you can use specific domains names so that only your website can embed that content.

Comment: Thanks, I will ask my provider to enable it. Can I then add sites that are allowed to embed my content in the iframe thus limit public access to selected domains? @Dessus

Comment: I added `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />` but it doesn't work for me eg. it still gives console error about not permitting cross-origin framing. See my question edited. @Dessus

Comment: I would recommend using the chrome debug tools, to see if that header is coming through in the network tab. If its not, you could try doing it via C# manually until you figure out how to do it in IIS.

Comment: I am checking it in the Network tab of debugging tool. Have you seen my edit above? I am simply unable to remove `x-frame-origin SAMEORIGIN` on some pages from the response header neither by setting other option in IIS or in `web.config`. I am getting the same result in Firefox and Chrome so it looks like not browser dependent.

Comment: Have you tried this suggestion for removing it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371125/removing-x-frame-options-being-added-automatically-only-in-login-page

Comment: yes I did and still `x-frame-ooptions SAMEORIGIN` persists. See my edit above