# How to remove X-FRAME-OPTIONS for views inside ASPNET CORE application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iframe

A similar question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371125/removing-x-frame-options-being-added-automatically-only-in-login-page) but I'm not sure how to fix this in dot net core.

I have a web application with many views, some of these views are used in another piece of software using iframes.

Some of these views work, but I have added two new ones recently and, for some reason, I couldn't use them in iframes. On closer inspection, I have seen that the two new views are adding X-FRAME-OPTIONS value to be SAMEORIGIN which is stopping them being displayed in iframes.

Two questions:

1. What could be the reason only the new views have this new X-FRAME-OPTIONS value of SAMEORIGIN?
2. How do I remove these headers from views?

EDIT

I have found that this only happens when the view contains form data which binds to the asp actions.

The following doesn't work and auto adds the X-IFRAME-OPTIONS header:

```
<form asp-action="myAspAction_1" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="my-form">
      <div style="text-align: center; margin: auto;">
           <label>Choose file: </label><input asp-for="myAspAction_2" onchange="changeFnc()" style="width: 200px; text-align: center; margin: auto;" />
      </div>
      <input id="input-box-1" type="submit" value="My value" disabled="true" style="width:200px; margin:20px" />
 </form>
```

If I remove the asp-action and asp-for, it works:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="my-form">
          <div style="text-align: center; margin: auto;">
               <label>Choose file: </label><input onchange="changeFnc()" style="width: 200px; text-align: center; margin: auto;" />
          </div>
          <input id="input-box-1" type="submit" value="My value" disabled="true" style="width:200px; margin:20px" />
     </form>
```

Comment: there can be multiple ways to suppress the 'X-FRAME-OPTIONS' headers by old views (by your old teammates), 
does the issue persists if you have your view connected to an old controller where the other views work ?

Comment: @ModarNa good point, I've tested my new view in an old controller and it still fails to work

Comment: I cannot think of a reason why the old views would act differently unless they are specified to do that by something, I would scan a working view, check where it is referenced and so on check if it inherits some custom class and other decoration attributes. sorry but there aren't many leads for me.

Comment: @ModarNa i have narrowed it down and edited the original question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In asp.net core you can add the following code to `ConfigureServices` method in Startup.cs to skip the restrict:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(o => o.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true);
```

Comment: I found this before asking the question and it didn't work. I put it at the end of the method, when I tried it at the beginning, it worked. Must be conflicting with something else in the method. Thanks for the answer