# Using cookie authentication and POST in an iFrame (iFrame content is ASP MVC Core, parent site 3rd party)

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, post, cookies, iframe

I have read through many answers on this topic but none seem to apply to what I am trying to do (or I am misunderstanding the problem entirely).  Where a lot of my confusion lies is around whether it's the parent window or the iFrame that needs settings changed.

We have a small portal that allows users of our customers (asp mvc core 6 multi tenant app) to login and view their data.  So far it works great, all but 1 of our customers do not  iFrame the portal, we are trying to make it so they can frame our portal.  They have their own domain.

Our authentication is the regular ASP Identity using cookies that is built in to the framework.

I've recreated a similar setup, I have a simple parent site that has this (the sub domain is their own sub domain to our site and if you go there you get the regular portal).

```
<div class="text-center">
<iframe src="https://sub.ourdomain.com" width="525" height="800" name="b3iframe"></iframe>
```

So far anything I do other than link to a new page fails within the iFrame.  I can't POST a form, use AJAX, etc.  Another problem is even if try to log them in (without POSTING a form, just hardcoded login for testing) the cookie does not set and the portal returns to the login page.

- I have tried setting 'same-site=none' on both the parent and the framed site. (like what [this describes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-asp-net-and-asp-net-core/)).
- I have tested simple things like making a fetch request and that fails (I get a 302)
- All POST calls fail (even ones that don't require authentication, just test pages fail with a 400). When I get the 400 response code it is displayed within the frame.
- I am aware and have used the ability to pass messages between the parent and iFrame but I don't think that can solve the cookie/POST problem.
- I have tried using the 'target' attribute on the form to point to the iFrame but it appears that is for situations where the form is not inside the frame

The iFrame code can be just a simple login form:

```
<form method="post" id="loginForm">
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Email Address</label>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="UserName" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Password</label>
    <div>
        <input asp-for="Password" type="password" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="mt-5">
    <button type="submit" style="width:100%" class="btn btn-primary tenant-custom-button">Log in</button>                   
</div></form>
```

What's frustrating is even in a mock parent website that I made and have full control of I can't seem to set it up so that the iFrame can use cookies or POST/GET (the test parent website is also ASP MVC CORE). The only thing I can do is have links to other pages without auth or POSTS.

Thanks for your time,
Brian

Comment: Maybe check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371125/removing-x-frame-options-being-added-automatically-only-in-login-page  For cookies, you'll probably need to set them from same domain.  So the parent won't have access to them if I understand the setup here.  You would need to pass those along if they are a different domain... if they are sub-domain/domain, you should be fine with cookie set to *.domain.com.  As long as ASP.NET is not setting a strict same-site attribute to the cookie the *.domain.com cookie will also work on sub-domains.

Comment: The reverse is not true... so if not specified, setting a cookie from subdomain would be set to subdomain.domain.com, which would not work on domain.com.  Whereas setting from domain.com would work on subdomain.domain.com.  (Don't think the "*" part is necessary.. just set for domain.com would work on all subdomains...)

Comment: Thanks pcalkins, the cookies are from the 'framed' site.  In this case ourcustomer.ourwebsite.com.  I don't need the parent to be aware of anything.  The part that is most confusing is that I can't even post the login form in where the auth cookie would be generated (I get a 400 and nothing in our logs).  I can only generate the cookie manually but then it doesn't appear in the list of cookies available (in chrome right clicking on lock icon)

Comment: see the thread I linked to... sounds like x-frame-options.  It could also be that you are missing an anti-forgery token...(include "@Html.AntiForgeryToken()" in your form) that should be on by default along with the restrictions for frames.  Also consider security implications of allowing framed login.  There are various ways to tighten the frame-sandbox, but it sounds like that would be up to your clients.

Comment: FWIW, if some one comes across this, and I don't know the exact underlying reason, but our portal uses Razor Pages.  I built a controllers/views login page and that works fine, but anytime I POST a page in an iframe with Razor Pages it does not work and you get a 302 from chrome.  I'll update when/if I find out why and if this is unique to our site.